# Printing elements of an array without repeating an element

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a java class which involves a String array and two for loops

for going through the array elements and prints them plus their redundancy in the

array as they are Strings .

I want someone help me to print each element (String) one time only even it

repeated in the array.

The following code prints some element in the array more than one time.

So comparison between elements of the array Needed

```
 public class myClassName {

 static String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khaled"};

      public static String [] getArray()

      {

      String str[] = new String[myArray.length];

     for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)

       {

       str[i] = myArray[i].toString();

        }

       return str;

     }

     public static void main( String [] args)

     {

     String d [] = getArray();

     int noOftimesRepeated;

          for(int i=0;i<getArray().length;i++)

          {

          noOftimesRepeated=1;

          String currentName = d[i];

          for(int j=0;j<getArray().length;j++)

          {

          if(i!=j && d[i].equalsIgnoreCase(d[j]))

          {

          noOftimesRepeated = noOftimesRepeated+1;

          }


          }

          int j =0;


          System.out.println(d[i]+"\t" +"\t"+noOftimesRepeated);

  }

 }
```

}

Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

I have a second trial but it out prints the one element and it redundancy

only.

```
 public class Javafool {

      static String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khalo","Valderama"};

     static String str2[] = new String[myArray.length];


     public static String [] getArray()
      {

      String str[] = new String[myArray.length];


      for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)

      {

      str[i] = myArray[i].toString();

      }

      return str;

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

      String d [] = getArray();

      int noOftimesRepeated;

       sort(myArray);

       int no_of_repeat=1;

        String temp =null;

     int i   ;

      for(  i = 0;i<myArray.length-1;i++)

       {

           temp = myArray[i];

         myArray[i] = myArray[i+1];

         myArray[i+1] = temp;

       if(myArray[i].equals(temp))

       {

       no_of_repeat=  ++no_of_repeat;

       }

     }

      System.out.println(myArray[i]+""+temp+"\t"+"\t\t"+no_of_repeat);

      }

     public static void sort(String [] array) {

       String temp = null;

       for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
             {

         for(int i = 0; i<array.length-1;i++)
              {
           if(array[i].compareTo(array[i+1])<0)
                {

         temp = array[i];

         array[i] = array[i+1];

         array[i+1] = temp;

           }

           }}}}
```

Comment: I upvoted both answers. If your need is only to remove duplicates, use  arjacsoh's solution. If you need to count occurrences of each String, use lulyon's solution.

Comment: Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

Comment: Is it a requirement to absolutely avoid `java.util.*` package? I see some solutions without it (manual sorting?) but it is nearly equivalent as the methods exposed in `java.util` and it will likely be error prone.

Comment: s it a requirement to absolutely avoid java.util.* package? Yes Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,(The following solution doesn't involve java.util

package , and it depends on Quicksort Algorithm).

Thank you all.

```
     public class Javafool 

     {

static String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khalo","Valderama","Daoud"};

static String str2[] = new String[myArray.length];

     public static void main(String[] args)

     {

     int [] noOftimesRepeated;

      sort(myArray);

      int no_of_repeat=1;

      String temp =null;

       int i   ;

       int count = 0;

       String previous = null;

      for (String s : myArray) 

      {

     if (s.equals(previous))

     {

     count++;
     } 

     else 

     {

     if( previous !=null)

     System.out.println(previous + " :" + count);

     previous = s;

     count = 1;

     }

     }

     if (myArray.length > 0)

    {

    System.out.println(previous + " :" + count);

    }

    }

   public static void sort(String [] array) {

   String temp = null;

   for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)

  {

 for(int i = 0; i<array.length-1;i++)

  {

  if(array[i].compareTo(array[i+1])<0)

  {

  temp = array[i];

  array[i] = array[i+1];

  array[i+1] = temp;

 }

 }

    } } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the Strings to `Set<String>`, which eliminates duplicate values, and then print them:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Khaled", "Valderama",...);
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(list);

for(String s : set)
  System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map<String, Integer>`, String for the input string, Integer for the `noOftimesRepeated` counter.

Example:

```
Map<String , Integer> map = new HashMap<String , Integer>(); 

// Add and count str Repeated times.
map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);

// output string and counter pair in map
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun I have a more manual approach(require more code of course) by sorting the array first and count the neighbored strings. But the time complexity is o(nlogn), better than two nested forloop, which is o(n^2).

Comment: @Ruchira Thank you. code is not complete here, just an example.

Comment: @lulyon Is  your  new manual approach avoids java.util.*; package?

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun It could be. The first step, sorting, which can be manually implementing with Quicksort algorithm. The second step(counting the neighbored strings by a pass for string array) is itself avoid using java package.

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun Quicksort code here http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely don't want to use **java.util**, you can still sort by hand and remove adjacent duplicates :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khaled"};
  sort(myArray);

  String last=null;
  for(int i = 0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    if(last==null || !myArray[i].equals(last)) {
      last = myArray[i];
      System.out.print(last+", ");
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Very naive method to sort elements. You can improve this with a merge sort.
 * Arrays.sort() would do the same job in a better way.
 */
public static void sort(String [] array) {
  String temp = null;

  for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length-1;i++) {
      if(array[i].compareTo(array[i+1])<0) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is good as not repeating the displaying of  elements  but it doesn't count the number a of String redundancy

Comment: You have a sorted array. It is not very difficult to count occurrences of adjacent elements.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {

 String d [] = getArray();

     int noOftimesRepeated;

     sort(myArray);
    int no_of_repeat=1;
    String temp =null;
int i   ;
  for(  i = 0;i<myArray.length-1;i++)
  {
        temp = myArray[i];
        myArray[i] = myArray[i+1];
        myArray[i+1] = temp;

  if(myArray[i].equals(temp)
                )
  {

  no_of_repeat=  ++no_of_repeat;

  


  }` I  changed  little into your code , now the code can prints the number of redundancy for one element only , can you guide me more plz?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myArray = Arrays.asList("Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khaled");

    Set<String> sets = new HashSet<String>();

    sets.addAll(myArray);

    System.out.println(sets);
}
```

Output:  `[Khaled, Valderama, Rasheed, Daoud]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below,

```
String[] myArray = { "Khaled", "Valderama", "Daoud", "Khaled",
        "Rasheed", "Daoud", "Valderama", "Khaled" };
Set<String> sets = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sets.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`. `Set` will avoid adding duplicates.

```
    String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud",
                        "Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khaled"};
    Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
    for(String i:myArray){
        set.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(set);
```

If you don't want to use `java.util.*` package try following way.

```
  String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud",
                       "Valderama","Khaled"};
    String[] newArr=new String[myArray.length];
    int j=0;
    for(String i:myArray){
        if(!Arrays.toString(newArr).contains(i)){
            newArr[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun you can try my second way.

Comment: but your code involves Arrays which is a class in java.util. package

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using *Set*, you can also create a list of unique items.

```
String [] myArray = {"Khaled", "Valderama", "Daoud", "Khaled", "Rasheed", "Daoud", "Valderama", "Khaled"};
List<String> myPrintList = new ArrayList<String>();        

for(String str : myArray){            
    if(!myPrintList.contains(str)){ // Check first if myPrintList contains the item already
        myPrintList.add(str); // Add if the list doesn't contain that item
    }
}

// Print list
for(String str : myPrintList){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

**EDIT** based from comment:

Not sure why you do not want to use util package, but-

```
String [] myArray = {"Khaled", "Valderama", "Daoud", "Khaled", "Rasheed", "Daoud", "Valderama", "Khaled"};
StringBuilder uniqueNames = new StringBuilder(); // For storing all unique names separated by a pipe (|)        

for(String str : myArray){

    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(str) < 0){ // Check if str exists in builder yet
        uniqueNames.append(str); // Add str if it doesn't exist
        uniqueNames.append("|"); // Add delimiter                
    }

}

String[] myPrintArray = uniqueNames.toString().split("\\|"); // Get an array by splitting using the pipe delimiter

for(String str : myPrintArray){        
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

Answer (score 0):

You dun need 2 for loop to do it. Just this 3 line of code will do! :D

```
final List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khaled");
    final Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(lst);
    System.out.printf("Unique values: ", set);
```

If without *ulit package

You will need a custom sort method. 
The pseudo code can goes like that (Not a efficient way of doing)

```
"Given" lst array; 
Array temp = new Araay(lst.lenght); 

//two for loop for 
(int i = 0; i< lst.lenght; i++) { 
if(i==0){ 
temp[i] = lst[i]; // first array 
} 
for (int u = 0 ; u < lst.lenght; u ++){ 
//Write a code here if the lst[i] string is not equal to any temp[u] string, add then inside. Else dun care :) Cheers! 
} 
}
```

Comment: Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun Yes there is, You will need a custom sort method.
The pseudo code can goes like that (Not a efficient way of doing )

"Given" lst array;
Array temp  = new Araay(lst.lenght);

//two for loop
for (i = 0; i< lst.lenght; i++)
{
if(i==0){
 temp[i] = lst[i]; // first array
 }
for (u = 0 ; u < lst.lenght; u ++){
//Write a code here if the lst[i] string is not equal to any temp[u] string, add then inside. Else dun care :) Cheers! 
}

}

Answer (score 0):

try this. The for Loop will not be running fully for duplicate items

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class myClassName {

 static String [] myArray = {"Khaled","Valderama","Daoud","Khaled","Rasheed","Daoud","Valderama","Khaled"};
      public static String [] getArray()
      {
          String str[] = new String[myArray.length];
          for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
          {
              str[i] = myArray[i].toString();
          }
       return str;
     }

     public static void main( String [] args)
     {
         String d [] = getArray();
         int noOftimesRepeated;
         ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          for(int i=0;i<getArray().length;i++)
          {
              if(list.contains(d[i]))
                    continue;
              noOftimesRepeated=1;

              for(int j=0;j<getArray().length;j++)
              {
                  if(i!=j && d[i].equalsIgnoreCase(d[j])  )
                  {
                      noOftimesRepeated = noOftimesRepeated+1;
                      list.add(d[i]);
                  }
              }
              System.out.println(d[i]+"\t" +"\t"+noOftimesRepeated);

          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please Is there any solution without using .util.* package

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous guy, firstly you should make you arraylist in a sequence, you can try the Quicksort algorithm，secondly you should compare current element with the previous one, if they equal, do not print it. it is easy, right?

you can extract your quicksort algorithm function to a util class, so you can use it in later development.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrays are fixed size in memory and you can't drop the duplicated values from the array.

So either you transfer the duplicated values to unwanted values (like zeros or any string), or you use an `ArrayList`, which allows you to drop values from the list (because lists are not fixed size and you can change it).